# Blade PHP file displays blade code in the browser

Tags: php, html, laravel-blade

Everytime I run index.blade.php, the blade code displays in the browser, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I am using atom and I have blade at the bottom right instead of PHP so I am confused, I also installed a blade package on atom but the package only highlights the code, any suggestions?

I tried adding PHP tags before the php and after the PHP

index.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewpoert" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Simple Like Dislike System</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="blog-header">
        <h1>Like & Dislike System</h1>
        <p>Laravel 5.5 Like and Dislike System and using Ajax</p>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="blog-post">
          @foreach ($posts as $post)
             <div class="post" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">
               <a href="#"><h3>{{$post->title}}</h3></a>
               <h6>Posted on {{$post->created_at}} by {{$post->user->name}}</h6>
               <p>{{$post->body}}</p>
               <div class="interaction">
                 <a href="#">Like</a>
                 <a href="#">Dislike</a>
                 <hr>

               </div>
             </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you acessing the file directly, like "localhost/index.blade.php"? That's not how it's suposed to work.

Comment: Yes, we are using localhost/index.blade.php. Because when we tested it in our laravel it did the same thing, what's wrong with viewing method we are using right now?

Comment: You need to use the engine to render the view, through some route. Read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data

Comment: How would we use the engine to render the view? What are you reffering to when you give the docs link, because we are using laravel 5.5

Comment: If I were to use this code                                                 Route::get('blade', function () {
    return view('child');
}); Where would you suggest I place it?